# resultant of 3 vectors along sides of equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

It is a homework problem, but I really don't quite understand the question. It reads-

"3 forces of magnitudes 10N, 20N, and 30N acting on a point are parallel to the sides of an equilateral triangle, taken in order. Find their resultant"

What I think is, as the resultant of 3 vectors forming a closed figure is 0, the answer should be 0.But the answer is given as $10 \sqrt{3}$. How?

Thanks in advance! (PS- Please add a diagram, if possible)

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know from the question that the forces are in the *same direction* as the sides of the equilateral triangle, so they are at 60 degrees to each other. They all have different magnitudes so cannot possibly form an equilateral triangle if placed "end-to-end".

To work out the answer, you can calculate the horizontal and vertical components of each of the forces, add these separately and re-express as a new vector, e.g.

$$\vec R = \vec a + \vec b + \vec c = \begin{bmatrix}a_x\\a_y \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}b_x\\b_y \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}c_x\\c_y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a_x + b_x + c_x\\a_y+b_y+c_y \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: I am getting $10\sqrt{31}$ instead of $10\sqrt{3}$ for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

The equilateral triangle only tells you the directions of the vectors.  The vectors must be ``floated'' so that they all act on the point.  Each vector has its own length.

Here's the diagram:

[image: Three vectors]

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, the length of a vector is proportional to the magnitude of whatever it represents. The vectors here are representing the direction only. With a representation of this sort, the resultant of 3 vectors forming an equilateral triangle is zero, only if their magnitude is the same. Because their magnitudes differ, they can't cancel each other out! When dealing with vectors, it helps to divide them into convenient components and add them accordingly. A convenient coordinate system in this case would be one where one of the axes is coinciding with one side of the triangle. That way you'd only need to split two vectors into components.